# How to see DB connections via JMeter?

Tags: database, concurrency, database-connection, jmeter, perfmon

M newbie to JMeter, Can we track the active DB connections via Jmeter?
Is there any parameter or thing in Jmeter which can do the job easier.

Right now I am just monitoring the DB connections via terminal. Is it possible with Jmeter

Answer (score 4):

Given that your database is MySQL:

1. Download [MySQL Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/), extract `mysql-connector-java-x.x.xx-bin.jar`, drop it to /lib folder of your JMeter installation, restart JMeter
2. Add [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to the test plan. Configure it as follows:

   - Number of threads: `1`
   - Ramp-up: `1`
   - Loop Count: tick `Forever`
3. Add [JDBC Connection Configuration element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration). Configure it as follows:

   - Variable Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `test`
   - Database URL: `jdbc:mysql://your_mysql_host:3306/information_schema`
   - JDBC Driver Class: `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`
   - provide your credentials as well
4. Add [JDBC Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request). Configure it the next way:

   - Variable Name: `test` or what you have entered in the JDBC Connection Configuration element
   - SQL Query: `select * from PROCESSLIST;`
5. Add [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer). Set "Thread Delay" to be i.e. 5000
6. Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

Above config will query MySQL server each 5 seconds and results will go to the View Results Tree listener.

[image: JDBC Process List]

If you use other RDBMS server the approach should be the same, however JDBC driver binary, driver class name, URL and SQL query will be different.

See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/secret-building-database-test-plan-with-jmeter) for extra information on database testing with Apache JMeter.